# R: How to use turn the output of a function into a constant

Tags: r

Let's say I have some lines of code which produce a constant `z` , which I then use in the creation of a function `myFunc`.

```
y <- 1.5
z <- y * 3

myFunc <- function(x){x * z + 5}
```

I then save `myFunc` for some later use.

```
save(myFunc, file = "C:\\Functions\\myfunc")
```

When I load this function, however, it is still referencing the output of `z`, which I may no longer have in my environment (unless I save `z` along with `myFunc`).

My question is, when creating `myFunc`, is there some way to incorporate the *value* of `z` instead of a reference to the variable?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

why not add `z` as a parameter to your function?

```
myFunc <- function(x,z=5){x*z +5}
myFunc(3)
[1] 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the body of a function. In your simple example, z could be replaced with value like this (you have to find `z` in the expression tree):

```
body(myFunc)[[2]][[2]][[3]] <-  z
myFunc
# function (x) 
# {
#     x * 4.5 + 5
# }
```

Or you could change the function body from a parsed expression:

```
body(myFunc) <- parse(text = sprintf("{ x * %f + 5 }", z))
```

The way around messing with function body would be adding an attribute to the function:

```
myFunc <- function(x){
  if(!is.null(attr(myFunc, "z"))) 
    z <- attr(myFunc, "z")
  x * z + 5
}
attr(myFunc, "z") <- z
```